# Unix - randomly select lines based on column values

Tags: bash, unix, random

I have a file with ~1000 lines that looks like this:

```
ABC C5A 1
CFD D5G 4
E1E FDF 3
CFF VBV 1
FGH F4R 2
K8K F9F 3
... etc
```

I would like to select 100 random lines, but with 10 of each third column value (so random 10 lines from all lines with value "1" in column 3, random 10  lines from all lines with value "2" in column 3, etc).

Is this possible using bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use `awk`, you can do the same with a one-liner

```
sort -R file | awk '{if (count[$3] < 10) {count[$3]++; print $0}}'
```

Answer (score 7):

First `grep` all the files with a certain number, shuffle them and pick the first 10 using `shuf -n 10`.

```
for i in {1..10}; do
    grep " ${i}$" file | shuf -n 10
done > randomFile
```

If you don't have `shuf`, use `sort -R` to randomly sort them instead:

```
for i in {1..10}; do
    grep " ${i}$" file | sort -R | head -10
done > randomFile
```